# Generar array de acuerdo a opciones escogidas React

Tags: json, reactjs, api

Tengo 2 Objetos JSON en mi interfaz de react
primero es : `preguntas`
segundo es : `opciones`

al momento de darle click en alguna opción de las preguntas me retorna un valor gracias a

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({  
    [e.target.name] :e.target.value
  })
}
```

este es mi componente

```
         render(){

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div><img src={LogoBoxi}></img></div>
        {
            this.state.preguntaYRespuestas.map((pregunta)=>(
              <div>
                <h1  name={pregunta.id} > {pregunta.pregunta}</h1>
                <div>
                    {
                        pregunta.respuestas.map((respuesta)=>(
                            <input type="button" onClick={this.handleChange} name={`${pregunta.id}`} value={respuesta.opcion} key={`${pregunta.id}_${respuesta.id}`}></input>    
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
        }
</div>
      );

      }
```

Este es el resultado en pantalla 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que obtengo al momento de darle click en alguna opcion de la respuesta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiro convertir las respuestas que escogi en un objeto JSON, ¿Como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Hola @Sebas. Se refiere a las respuestas que están en su `State`?. Si es ello, de por sí ya es un objeto.

Comment: se crea el objeto pero como hago para guardarlo? , es para realizar una funcion, dependiendo de las opciones que se escoja me retorne un valor, por ejemplo : si la mayoria escojio la opcion 1, entonces enviar una alerta escogio opcion 1, si me hago entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Acá te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- Se recorre una lista de preguntas y respuestas
- Se guarda en el **state** la pregunta con la respuesta seleccionada
- Se muestra en la etiqueta **code** las preguntas y respuestas seleccionadas en formato de **array** convertido a **string**.

**Ejemplo online:** https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-platform-zpnk3

**JAVASCRIPT/REACTJS**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import preguntaYRespuestas from "./data";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    resultado: []
  };

  handleOnChange = (id, opcion) => {
    const { resultado } = this.state;
    const copiaResultado = [...resultado];
    const indice = resultado.findIndex(r => r.id === id);

    if (indice < 0) {
      copiaResultado.push({ id, opcion });
    } else {
      copiaResultado[indice] = {
        id,
        opcion
      };
    }

    this.setState({
      resultado: [...copiaResultado]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {preguntaYRespuestas.map(pregunta => (
          <div key={`${pregunta.id}`}>
            <h1>{pregunta.pregunta}</h1>
            <div>
              {pregunta.respuestas.map(respuesta => (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.handleOnChange(pregunta.id, respuesta.opcion)
                  }
                  key={`${pregunta.id}_${respuesta.id}`}
                >
                  {respuesta.opcion}
                </button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div>
          <p>Respuestas seleccionadas:</p>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(this.state.resultado)}</code>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EJEMPLO DE DATOS (data.js)**

```
export default [
  {
    id: "p1",
    pregunta: "Qué color te gusta más?",
    respuestas: [
      {
        id: "p1r1",
        opcion: "rojo"
      },
      {
        id: "p1r2",
        opcion: "verde"
      },
      {
        id: "p1r3",
        opcion: "azul"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "p2",
    pregunta: "Qué te gustaría comprar?",
    respuestas: [
      {
        id: "p2r1",
        opcion: "casa"
      },
      {
        id: "p2r2",
        opcion: "auto"
      },
      {
        id: "p2r3",
        opcion: "computadora"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre, que podrias crear en tu state un objeto `resultado` y que vayas agregando cada respuesta que seleccionen,

```
state = {
  resultado: {}
}

// aqui estarias copiando lo que haya en resultado y agregando  la respuesta seleccionada 
// mira que se usa un callback en setState para poder obtener el state previo
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
     return {
       resultado: {...prevState.resultado, ...{[e.target.name]: e.target.value }}
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: me da error de sintaxis, no logro saber cual sea el error

Comment: Ya lo encontre, faltaba el let en resultado!, gracias!

Comment: creo que tambien faltaba el return en el setstate, modifique la respuesta con el cambio

Comment: mmm creo que si, al momento de dar click me aparece TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null, porque sera?